# Special case when calling InvokeScript with WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, browser, webbrowser-control

I am trying to use InvokeScript method on the WebBrowser control to execute a script on the web page that has been loaded into my WebBrowser control.  If I am calling just a simple javascript function, this works properly. However, the javascript function that I am trying to call is nested within a variable like this:

```
var holder = 
{ 
    DoA: function() 
    {
         ....
    },
    DoB: function()
    {
         .....
    }
}
```

Calling holder.DoA works fine when called from within the javascript, but the function is not called successfully when I try to call it from within my C# code like this:

```
object obj1 = m_webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("holder.DoA");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I got it to work like this:

```
m_webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { "holder.DoA()" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried window.holder.DoA as the parameter to InvokeScript ?

Comment: I tried this and it still did not work:

m_webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("window.holder.DoA");

Answer (score 0):

That's a singleton JSON class. If holder is a global variable, you can get its reference by calling [IHTMLDocument::Script](http://google.com/codesearch?hl=en&sa=N&filter=0&q=IHTMLDocument+C%23+script++lang:c%23&ct=rr&cs_r=lang:c%23).

I am not sure whether Type.InvokeMember would work on a JSON object since the methods are added at runtime, try query [IDispatchEx](http://google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=IDispatchEx++lang:c%23&sbtn=Search) interface from the object to call the methods.